# What is the use of @ Javadoc view in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I noticed @javadoc view in my eclipse. Could you please tell me what is the use of this and how to use it.

[image: I never see anything here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse actually does provide decent tools for creating your own JavaDoc, which is a good idea, as then others who have to use your code will have the ability to see what it does.

- There is a keyboard shortcut for adding a block for a class or method (on Mac it's Command-Shift-J I think, but search Javadoc in the key mappings.
- You can define templates for adding things like links, which are pretty important, that make creation of JavaDoc go very quickly
- When you document in Eclipse, it is intelligent enough to point to existing docs, so say you make an interface, you document the methods in the interface, then inside each implementer, if you created them after the interface, you will get a block that points you back to the interface

When you have added your own, or other people on your team have, this view let's you see what that will look like, so it's got a dual purpose: for making it easier to read the markup of others' JavaDoc, and for previewing your own.

Answer (score 0):

The view you are showing is the Eclipse @ **Javadoc view**. The **Javadoc view** shows the Javadoc of the element selected in the Java editor or in a Java view.

To use it, simply open a Java file that contains Javadoc in the Java view (or use the Java perspective). Once you do so the **Javadoc view** will automatically populate.